# US Politics, any grass root like campaign fighting the new tax increase

Tags: democracy, campaigning, liberalism, grassroots

I just found out from my employer that our social security tax just increase by 2%, which were never publicized as much in the media. I live in NY, a very liberal state, so it would make sense why it was kept hidden.

So are there any campaigns anyone know or any petition I can sign to voice my outrage in the tax increase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Payroll taxes rose by 2% as part of the fiscal cliff deal](http://www.nydailynews.com/news/national/payroll-tax-rise-article-1.1231335), which was passed only two days ago, so it's unsurprising that you didn't get much advance notice, whatever state you are in. On the other hand there has been a lot of publicity about it since it was passed. The New York Times has all the details. And technically taxes didn't go up as a result of the deal, the taxes were scheduled to go up anyway as part of last year's deal. If this deal hadn't passed, taxes would have gone up a lot more.

I'm sure there are plenty of people expressing their opinions to their elected representitives.

Comment: This technically was an expiration of a payroll tax holiday, so payroll taxes reverted to 2009 levels.

Comment: Link to the ny times article?

Comment: Oops, I meant the link I had already put up, which isn't the NYT. Here's a Forbes link: http://www.forbes.com/sites/advisor/2013/01/03/fiscal-cliff-deal-4-tax-provisions-handled-1-hiked-still-work-to-be-done/